# Login validation algorithms

Tags: security, authentication

I know of one -

```
SELECT * FROM log_records WHERE 'username'=uname AND 'password'=pass;
if(row_count==1)
    return true;
return false;
```

The questions are:

- Is the above algorithm a 'best practice'?
- Are there any alternatives to the above algorithm?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, what platform are you developing in? You might get more specific guidance if you tag the questions with your environment, as many platforms already offer authentication/membership mechanisms. Most of your questions seem to deal with PHP... Is it safe to assume you're looking for guidance specific to PHP?

Comment: Yes, I am indeed using PHP. Nevertheless, general guidelines are also welcome.

Comment: In that case, I would refer you to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624846/php-best-practices-for-user-authentication-and-password-security

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is NOT a best practice.

- First, it would only work if the username and password were unencrypted.
- Second it's hopelessly vulnberable to SQL Injection and I could steal all of your user credentials in about 3 seconds with that SQL statement.

Start here for best practices:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Authentication

Your best bet is to use an existing membership provider for whatever environment you're developing in, rather than building your own, or better yet, using OpenID or a similar mehanism.

Even if the OWASP article is too in depth, PLEASE at least read this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/openid-does-the-world-really-need-yet-another-username-and-password.html

and this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

**One last edit**

This is the article I was REALLY looking for when I found those two above: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/12/the-dirty-truth-about-web-passwords.html

Comment: But I am making this for a B2B web-application (as SAAS model) and I therefore need to employ my own login management.

Comment: There are several PHO-specific answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624846/php-best-practices-for-user-authentication-and-password-security

Answer (score 0):

You could do this...

```
SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `log_records` WHERE `username` = uname
```

Assuming of course that `uname` is binded or escaped through the correct escaping mechanism.

If no rows, you would know the user does not exist.

You could then compare the user submitted password to the password for this user.

You could then internally log the specifics of this failed login.

Remember, don't tell the end user which failed. Use something generic such as *The username and/or password combination does not match*.

Answer (score 0):

That is a valid way of doing it. It's not included in your post, but I asume that pass is a encrypted version of the actual password?

The above statement does require the username to be unique, but it usually is.

A side note is that the above statement doesnt have to be case-sensitive. Some database compare textual data in text format instead of bit format. This would mean that logging in with password 'MyPasSworD' would work, but 'mypassword' would work aswell.

Comment: Yes the password is encrypted. As for the case sensitive thing, I feel its better to keep to the naming conventions/standards even if technology allows leeway. :)

Answer (score -1):

i'm using this pseudo code algo.

- start

  - sanitize inputs
  - check username if exist
  - get username's password if exist
  - if using an enryption, encrypt the entered password
  - compare username's password to the the entered password
  - do some stuff
- end