# How to login in PHP using md5

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication, md5

I have made an register script with `md5` but now I have to log in with it. I have tried many things but it didn't work.

This is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {
include_once("Connect.php");
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$_POST['password']);
$password = md5($_POST['password']);//hashing pass 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = '{$username}' and userPassword = '{$password}'";

$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($count > 1)
{

    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $userId = $row[0]; // takes id from DataBase
    $dbUsername = $row[1]; // takes username from DataBase
    $dbPassword = $row[2]; // takes userpass from DataBase
    $_SESSION['password'] = $dbPassword;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $dbUsername;
    $_SESSION['id'] = intval($userId);
    $_SESSION['login'] = TRUE; // if username and pass are corrects it logs in
    header('location: login.php');
    die(); // using die() after header()

}
else {
    echo "incorrect username or password.";
}
}
```

thanks all for your comments.

the solution:

```
  $inlogcrypt = md5($password);



$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = '".$username."' and userPassword = '".$inlogcrypt."'";
```

Comment: **Do not** hash passwords with MD5. Use the Password Hashing API of PHP. There exists a compatibility script on GitHub if you don't have PHP 5.5 yet.

Comment: What does that mean you tried many things? that did'nt work? What have you tried and what didnt work?

Comment: The code is right if in the database the column `userPassword` it's saved the value `md5`

Comment: @bub i have tried different code's but none of them worked

Comment: @Furkanyavuz is the password field large enough to store the md5 key?

Comment: This `Connect.php` is unknown as to which MySQL API is used to connect with. `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? You omitted the HTML form that should have been posted, and we don't know if it does contain form tags, if a post method is used and if all elements bear the matching name attributes. MD5 produces a 32-length string, so make sure the password length is equal or greater to that. Make sure that no whitespace is being introduced. Other than this, there isn't anything else to ask. All I can is is this and check for errors. You're not doing that via PHP, and unknown if the session was started.

Comment: @Fred -ii- It connects with myslqli_. I have an 32-lenght string, and it doesn't show any errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to PHP, I wouldn't recommend starting with building a custom CMS.

To learn more about (different types of) authentication, you can:

- Read [this guide](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html) about basic authentication with PHP/PDO.
- Use [PHPAuth](https://github.com/PHPAuth/PHPAuth).
- Use [OpenID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624846/php-best-practices-for-user-authentication-and-password-security) so you don't have to handle login data.

The first link will show you how to

1. Use PDO instead of mysql(i).
2. Filter submitted data (although I'll admit they do it in a somewhat ugly way, but it's easy to understand).
3. Use `$SESSION` to store session data.
4. Use that same session data to require authentication on some pages.

Just know that logins contain sensitive data and there's a lot more you should learn before building a platform that you want people to use.

I just mentioned some things about logins, but you should also learn more about hashing (don't use md5 for logins, I recommend bcrypt) and program structures.

Comment: it is for a school project

Comment: The first guide explains all the details to get you started on basic authentication.

Comment: thanks for the guide. but we cant use an openID it has to be an registered account from our database

Comment: The guide isn't about OpenID, I just suggested  OpenID as an alternative. The first link uses PDO for a database connection and a very basic authentication structure.